# Laravel update model with another model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to update one model in database with all fields except id from other model.

For example i have two models

```
Model1: {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Name1",
    "address":"Adress1",
    "phone":"1234567"
}

Model2: {
    "id":null,
    "name":"Name2",
    "address":null,
    "phone":"777777"
}
```

How can update model1 with model2 values, so that model1 would have this values (all values from model2 except id)

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Name2",
    "address":null,
    "phone":"777777"
}
```

P.S. fill() method ignores null values, forceFill() uses nulls but also other fields from array for example attributed fields.

Comment: have you tried to use `except` ?

Comment: Convert model2 to array, except id and than fill model1 with this array? Yes i tried, this way makes model1 ignores null value of address field.

Comment: "P.S. fill() method ignores null values" can you explain this, fill does not ignore null input, how could you ever set values to null in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `attributesToArray()` and `fill()`. Properties need to be fillable.

```
$properties = array_only($model1->attributesToArray(), ['name', 'address', 'phone']);

$model2->fill($properties);
```

Comment: alternatively you can use array_except and exclude id :)

Comment: mrhn thanks for answer, yes you answer is right and fill method does not ignores null values. I had misunderstanding in creating model with $model = new Model($request->all()) . Creating model this way leaves not used fields not existing, so there is no not used model values when i convert model to array.

Comment: For example if my request has name="name1", and i create create $model = new Model($request->all()). After creating array with you method i get ["name" => "name1"] but there is no values id=>null, address=>null in this array. That was my problem.

Comment: But if they are null, why do you need to pass them, they will default to null anyways?

Comment: but you can define default values with protected $attributes = ['address' => '', 'phone' => null]; on your model and they should be sent.

Comment: I had to set null values explicitly because i use array from model to update (fill) another model, and if this array not contains null values of than updated model use its old field values. But using $attributes for setting default values solved all my problems. So thank you one more time)